# Yammer Analytics API

Tags: yammer

To give an context, we are trying to achieve reporting functionality based on the Yammer activity/usage information. 
Questions

1. We are not able to find any Analytics API in the link https://developer.yammer.com/documentation/  except Data Export API.  Please let us know if we have any other API related to usage Analytics.
2. Is there any way to execute our query against yammer big data for us to get the usage information?
   •   The data export is not providing the information such as ‘like’, ‘share’ and ‘followed by’.  Is there any other way to export yammer data including these missing items?
3. How to remove the deleted entries from the past collection just in case if we are going to do periodic data export?
4. How the third party tools companies like ‘good data’ will contact yammer for analytics data.  This will help us to find the approach involved in this.

Can someone help us on this.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/04/09/yammer-analytics-with-excel-and-power-bi.aspx Yammer API and Excel 2013 for bigger data..

Having said that - I think the tool is currently broken as I seem be be able to download 114% of my stats, then get some blank CSV files which then fail on power pivot.

You need to be a verified admin to access this tool.
Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 0):

About **Question 2**

There are good ways of doing it through the API. You can use Excel and PowerQuery or a home made .net data extractor. Like, Share and followed By are possible with the API but not with the useless Data Export feature. Be aware the API have some issues when trying to retrive all data. I'm currently trying to get these issues fixed.

About **Question 4**

They need the account of a trusted admin. Thanks to a Token they will be able to access all your networks messages and provide you most of the Analytics you need.

They have good webinards for their tool. Only issue is that they copy your data in their environment in the US (is not acceptable for European customers).